# In XNA, how should I organize content shared between projects?

Tags: xna, shaders, xna-content-pipeline

I have an XNA library using several custom effects.  They need to be accessed by:

1. a content pipeline project (models are built with the effect), and
2. projects that use my game library (they should be able to load a standalone instance of the effect).

Where should I put the `.fx` files for the custom effects?  How do I access them from separate projects?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the effects to a content project referenced by the game library project. I've done this for my own engine for effects, lighting textures, etc., that need to be accessible by both the engine and projects using the engine.

Simply add a new content project and make a content reference to it from the game library project. The effects will be built and embedded in the game library build and can be made accessible from outside the game library.